# Volume of sand in a cat box - ultrasonic sensor?

Tags: components, component-selection

My cat is always making fun of the sand that is inside of his sanitation zone :)

In order to better control the amount of sand that is present on the container I'm developing a communications circuit to collect data from the box. But I would like to develop something that could give me volume of the sand that is in the box. The idea is to collect values 4 times per day. Is it possible to achieve this with an ultrasonic sensor ? I have no experience with this kind of sensors. Any ideas or tips ?

I was also thinking in taking photos and having a service to analyse the photo. But this option is more time demanding and needs light adjustments...

The box has 100cm depth x 100cm width x 70cm height (I can expand if necessary, which will be for the sensor)

Can I make it with ultrasonic sensor ?

Thanks!

Best.

Comment: I'd be wary of using ultrasonic systems around cats unless you're sure they can't hear it.

Comment: I wonder if you either want to measure the level in some kind of storage container (70cm is quite hight for a litter box) or want to measure how much litter is currently in the box. In the second case your cat will disturb the surface (e.g. create pits) that make calculating the volume just from one distance measurement not reliable. In a storage container you would also have the option of measuring the level with e.g. a ball "floating" on the sand.

Comment: Just stick the box on a scale and measure the weight.

Comment: @pjc50 : yes! you REALLY don't want to scare the cat away from the litter box! Ultrasonic devices are sold to keep cats away from bird feeders... Just extract the load sensors from cheap kitchen scales and put one under each foot of the box.

Comment: Caution that scale load cells are zero'd (tared) at each power-on and you won't have that luxury so accuracy will be degraded.

Comment: What if the cat is in the box during a sensor read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to setup some sort of auto-refill or alerts based on litter box levels I would rather look into a system based on weight measurement setup to determine amount of litter present instead.

Although this would need to be adjusted for different brands of litter.

Comment: thanks for the help. I will use load cells, it's easy and simple.